# NSSet count unique entries compared to 2nd set

Tags: ios, arrays, string, count, nsset

I've got two sets and use isSubsetOfSet: to determine if the receiving set is all present in the other set. However, I need to figure out how many unique entries are in the receiving set when isSubsetOfSet: fails. For example:

```
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3"];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"1", @"3", @"4", @"5"];

if (![set1 isSubsetOfSet:set2]) {

    How many items are in set1 that are not in set2? The answer should be 1. (a string "2")
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `@distinctUnion` and other things like that ?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Comment: @Larme Are you referring to this: "@distinctUnionOfSets" ?

Comment: Yes, I think that's what you're looking for. And to get quickly the what you seem to want, you can use I think combined with `@count` .

Comment: This only looks at one object. I cannot compare between two objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a mutable copy of `set1`, and subtract `set2` from it, like this:

```
NSMutableSet *missing = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:set1];
[missing minusSet:set2];
```

Now `missing` contains all objects from `set1` missing in `set2`. You can skip the call of `isSubsetOfSet:`, comparing `missing.length` to zero instead.